# CHtmlView: Redirecting within OnNavigateError

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I am writing a MFC Windows C++ application which uses a CHtmlView to display a WebBrowser control in the UI. I am facing a problem with redirecting on HTTP errors. Before I begin with the question, let me say that it's not possible for me to use [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) or any other embeddable browser in this context.

I have a C++ class which derives from `CHtmlView` (WebBrowser control). That class calls `Navigate2` with a URL on initialization. In certain cases the navigation can lead to a 403 or a 404. I want to intercept that HTTP error and redirect to a page of my choosing or even retry by calling `Navigate2` again. However, when I call `Navigate2` from within `OnNavigateError` it doesn't seem to have any effect and the browser doesn't switch to the other URL.

```
void MyCHtmlView::OnNavigateError(LPCTSTR url, PCTSTR frame, DWORD error, BOOL *cancel) 
{
    *cancel = FALSE;
    Navigate2(error_url, NULL, NULL); // Doesn't navigate to error_url?!
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: In cases like this, I post myself a user-defined message, set `*cancel = TRUE`, and then re-navigate from the posted message's handler. This allows the existing operation to close properly before continuing.

Comment: Put a break point and debug for see.